Modifying a Tree at a specific location
I'm trying to modify a specific part of a tree at a given physical location. My approach was to extract the subtree using treeAt, modify it with a visit statement, and then update the original tree. However, I'm unsure how to properly update the initial tree after modifying the subtree.
Here’s what I’ve attempted so far:
Tree update(Tree tree, loc location) {
    TreeSearchResult[FunctionDeclaration] searchResult = treeAt(#FunctionDeclaration, location, tree);
    Tree subtree;
    if (treeFound(FunctionDeclaration foundTree) := searchResult) {
        subtree = foundTree;
    } else {
        throw "The given position (loc) is not found in the tree";
    }
    subtree = visit(tree) { ... }; // applying transformation

    // How to update the initial tree with the modified subtree ?

    return tree;
}

Is there a way to perform a visit operation directly at a specific location, something like visit(tree, loc)?

A visit also traverses the tree (it's like a switch, but than also on every sub-value of the value given). So you could write:
return visit(tree) {
    case FunctionDeclaration func => buildNewFunc(func)
       when func@\loc == location
};

The when clause is like a guard to the replacement.
Alternativly we can also write:
return visit(tree) {
    case FunctionDeclaration func: {
       if (func@\loc == location) {
           // calculate new tree
           // and then replace the original `func` with this tree
           insert newTree;
       }
    }
};

Note that the visit automatically returns the updated tree, not just the replaced part, but the argument passed in.

One element of visit is that it returns the entire transformed tree, and not only the subtree that matched. Perhaps we could add that to the answer, since the original question has subtree = visit .... it may clarify the answer.
